# How to open one browser in automation using ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I just want to know how to open one browser when i am going to test a loop. or how to clear the last inputted values in the login page to change it in the new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using watir-webdriver, you can instantiate a browser like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
```

If you want to clear text entry fields, you can use the `clear` method:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_1000000').set 'your name'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_1000000').clear
```

I pulled this info from http://watirwebdriver.com/, so you may want to check that out.